# How to convert Rails dynamic routes for Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a legacy Rails app which started life in Rails 1.2.
It has been converted through to Rails 5.0 over the years

The routes.rb file contains only two lines of 'wildcard routes' as follows

```
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))',:constraints => {:controller => /admin\/[^\/]+/}, :via =>  :all
  match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)', :via => :all
```

Links within the application are codedas in the following example:

```
<%= link_to('Marital Status', {:controller => 'marital_status', :action => 'list'})  %>
```

It appears that this sort of route is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.2

My question is how can I convert the routes to something that is acceptable to Rails 5.2.

Bear in mind that the application has about 150 controllers with a corresponding large number of actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am in a similar boat and for the time being I made a rake task to generate all of the routes and write them to the routes.rb file.

Using a little ruby meta-programming its pretty straight forward to find all the methods available to a class `<controller>.instance_methods` then filter out all of the built in rails methods + those inherited from the application controller.

update:

I used a rake task to generate routes and put the following code in the bottom of the routes file to log when a route was not found in production:

```
match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)', :via => :all, :to => proc { |env|
route = env["action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"]

Rails.logger.error("******************************************************************************************************")
Rails.logger.error("ROUTE NOT FOUND. USING WILDCARD ROUTE. REQUIRED ROUTE IS:>")
Rails.logger.error("#{env['REQUEST_METHOD'].downcase} #{route[:controller]}/#{route[:action]} => #{route[:controller]}##{route[:action]}")
Rails.logger.error("******************************************************************************************************")
controller = eval("#{route[:controller].camelize}Controller")
action = route[:action]
controller.action(action).call(env)}
```

Comment: This has been a God send answer for us.

Answer (score 0):

Because [match method has been deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5964), use get for GET and post for POST.

eg. `get '/list', to: 'marital_status#list'`

Comment: Your suggestion is exactly what I am trying to avoid. It would mean going through all 150 controllers and creating a route for each action which would end up being many hundreds of routes. I am looking for a more painless way of doing things. 'Restful Routes' and 'Named Routes' are all very well for new applications but to convert a legacy application would appear to be a nightmare. That's why I am looking for an alternative